# Selecionar em cada resposta valores diferentes com o Banco MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

Gostaria de saber como selecionar a quantidade de registros de uma tabela onde seleciona-se somente os valores maior que 6, porém em cada resultado fosse diferente, com o banco MySql, por exemplo:

```
Tabela Notas
Unidade I    |  Unidade II    |  Unidade III   | Unidade IV
10           |  4             |  7             | 3
1            |  3             |  7             | 9
7            |  0             |  8             | 1
```

Onde os valores maiores que 6 vão aparecer assim na consulta;

```
Unidade I    |  Unidade II    |  Unidade III   | Unidade IV
2 Registros  |  0 Registros   |  3 Registros   | 1 Registro
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Código funcional:

```
select
count(case when `Unidade I` > 6 then 0 end) as 'Unidade I',
count(case when `Unidade II` > 6 then 0 end) as 'Unidade II',
count(case when `Unidade III` > 6 then 0 end) as 'Unidade III',
count(case when `Unidade IV` > 6 then 0 end) as 'Unidade IV'
from Notas
```

> Note que caso o *nome do campo* na tabela possua *espaço*, deve-se
>   referenciá-la entre crases "`".

Comment: Resolvido, muito obrigado pessoal

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver este problema, é conforme abaixo

```
SELECT 
COUNT(CASE WHEN nota_valorI>6 then 1 ELSE NULL END) as "UNI_I",
COUNT(CASE WHEN nota_valorII>6 then 1 ELSE NULL END) as "UNI_II",
COUNT(CASE WHEN nota_valorIII>6 then 1 ELSE NULL END) as "UNI_III",
COUNT(CASE WHEN nota_valorIV>6 then 1 ELSE NULL END) as "UNI_IV"
from nota
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM
(

SELECT `Unidade I` AS UN FROM NOTAS
UNION 
SELECT `Unidade II` AS UN  FROM NOTAS
UNION
SELECT `Unidade III`AS UN  FROM NOTAS
UNION
SELECT `Unidade IV` AS UN  FROM NOTAS
) AS TA

WHERE UN  > 6
```